# SmartSVN can not identify .a file?

Tags: macos, svn, version-control, version, smartsvn

I find a strange problem of SmartSVN:

If I add some files into the repository, most of them will be identified by smartsvn except .a files, I don't know if this is a setting problem issue or other things ......

Dose anyone met this problem before ? Could anyone give me some information about this ? Thanks very much :)

Comment: That is "identified by smartsvn" in terms of **Subversion**?

Comment: SmartSVN is just a client software for Subversion, I use it for version-control on MACOSX. When open it, it will show the repository files.But everytime when I drag new files into repository and try to do the 'add' operation, I just can not find the .a files in the SmartSVN, but it seems other format files are OK (like .h, .m etc.)......

Comment: And in finder, you can see these 'missing' .a files are all at the right place ...... I googled it but still can't figure it out ......

Comment: I know, what is SmartSVN... I just don't understand SmartSVN-specific terms. These files (extension) can be in ignored list. Check svn:ignore property of root folder. > The svn:ignore property contains a list of file patterns which certain Subversion operations will ignore. Perhaps the most commonly used special property, it works in conjunction with the global-ignores run-time configuration option (see the section called “Config”) to filter unversioned files and directories out of commands svn status, svn add, and svn import.

Comment: Whether global-ignores from Subversion's "config" file are used or not depends on SmartSVN's Project Settings - Working Copy - Global Ignores

Comment: I've checked ~/.subversion/config and found .a file is in the global-ignored list, Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem and I solved it.
Just click "View" and check "Ignored Files", when it shows to you just add it like other files

Answer (score 3):

You can go Project-Settings-Global ingnores-deactivated 
after that you can commit all your files (even .ds file, so be careful)